# redirecting with .htaccess from several URL with language

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have search and test for serveral days... but I am not able to make the redirect I need with .htaccess

I need to redirect all URLs ending with `page-about.html`

The website has 2 languages and I'd like to redirect:
`/es/*/page-about.html` => `/es/content/about`
`/en/*/page-about.html` => `/en/content/about`

How can I make it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
 RedirectMatch ^/(en|es)/+page-([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/content/$2
```

This will redirect :

```
http://example.com/en//page-about.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/en/content/about
```

Comment: It not was exactly what I need, but it help me to make the correct rule: RedirectMatch ^/(en|es)/(.*)/+page-about\.html$ /$1/content/about

Comment: I would have answered similarly until I saw something suspicious about the question formatting. The `*`'s got completely lost.

Comment: Yes ultimater, I don't know why the asteriks goes from original question :S